# jquery prepend after body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying this, to have content just after body tag.

```
  <script>jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
$('body').prepend('<h1>Hello World</h1>').hide().slideDown();
 } );</script>
```

I am able to see the content but animation is not working. please suggest where I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('<h1>Hello World</h1>').hide().prependTo('body').slideDown();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/acU3q/

The problem is that you are calling hide() and slideDown() on the body tag rather than the newly created H1.

Comment: You might want to slow it down a bit so you can see the animation : http://jsfiddle.net/acU3q/2/. +1